# why cant i modify list-cell css within ListView?

Tags: java, css, listview, javafx, scenebuilder

I want to make my list-cells appear with "pointer"/"hold" cursor when hovered.
I've managed to target the whole listView and added background-color etc, but its just like the list-cells does not exist. Do i need to set cell factory manually?

EDIT:
I got the answer that i dont need to specify the cells manually, calling .list-cell should be sufficent to add the style. My css should work fine because im managing to change background colors on other elements, just not .list-cell. I have also tried the fx-cursor

EDIT2:
I have now tested within scenebuilder Preview > Scene style sheets > add a style sheet, and within that document i put:

```
.list-cell{
-fx-cursor: pointer;
}
.test{
-fx-background-color: black;
}
```

Still no go when i preview with sample data.

EDIT3:
[Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/wTaTG)
The cursor does not show in screenshots, but i can show you that my css works, just not on list-cell.

### So far i've tried:

#### CSS:

```css
.list-cell{
    -fx-background-color:black;
    -fx-cursor: pointer;
}
#test .list-cell{
    -fx-background-color:black;
    -fx-cursor: pointer;
}
.test .list-cell{
    -fx-background-color:black;
    -fx-cursor: pointer;
}
```

#### JAVA:

```
teamListView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, 
javafx.scene.control.ListCell<String>>()
        {
            @Override
            public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> teamListView)
            {
                return new ListCell();
            }
        });
```

### Code:

My Controller:

```
public class MainPageController implements Initializable {
    public static ObservableList<String> data = 
FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private ListView<String> teamListView;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
       Team escala = new Team("Escala", "Conrad Adams", 4987000);
       ArrayList<Team> teams = new ArrayList<Team>();
       teams.add(escala);
       data.add(teams.get(0).getName());
       teamListView.setItems(data);

    }     

}
```

Comment: You do not need a custom cellFactory, but the second css rule is invalid. Furthermore you're never using the `-fx-cursor` property... Also we cannot be sure you're actually using `id` as id for a ancestor of the list cells.

Comment: im just using background color as a test, the background is not changing which is the problem

Comment: have you properly added the stylesheet? The css should be working and was when I tested it...

Comment: yes , i could Change background of other hboxes:( Edit: to answer if im using id names, i set them in scenebuilder which is why you cant see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a fix, i dont have an explanation though:

Changed

```
.list-cell{
-fx-cursor: hand;
}
```

To

```
.list{
}
.list-cell:filled:hover{
-fx-cursor: hand;
-fx-text-fill: dimgrey;
}
```

My first css element seems to be ignored somehow, the rest of them gets activated